# Tuning where not exists clause inside a insert statement

Tags: performance, oracle, where-clause, bulkinsert

AN insert statement is taking lot of time to insert nearly 4 billion records, Is there a better way to do the same insert without using where not exists?

```
insert /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(T1,16) */ into T1
select /*+ parallel(TABLE1,32) */
id,
id_date,
id_time,
id_cnt,
from SCHEMASRC.TABLE1
where not exists
  ( select 'X' from SCHEMASRC2.TABLE2 T2  where trim(T2.id) =  trim(TABLE1.id) );
```

3998267276 rows created.

Commit complete.
Elapsed: 04:58:32.75
commit work;

Comment: If this is Oracle, please add the tag. One thought - is there any way you can remove the need to `trim()` both id's, e.g. cleansing during the insert.

Comment: 5 hours to insert 4 billion records doesn't seem that bad.  But StuartLC's advice should improve it even more.

Comment: @StuartLC the trim() might be consuming some time but the other insert statements we have without trim are also taking 4+ hours. BTW I tried removing the trim but I couldn't

Comment: @Gordon A similar statement without not in where not exists is taking 11 mins and its inserting 51 million records. I checked indexing and rest everything seems to be in place so trying to figure out how to tune the "WHERE NOT EXISTS" clause.

Comment: @user3570198 . . . Let's see.  4 billion is about 80 times 51 million.  80 * 11 minutes is 880 minutes which is over 14 hours.  I think you are doing much better than expected.  I wonder why this is so much faster, not why it is so slow.

Comment: Trim will make join indexes not usable. Why do you need the trim on an id field you are using for joins? 

You can also try alternative syntax like MERGE though I'm not sure how that works with parallel processing. Can do a left outer join from table1 to table2 then keep records where table2 non-nullable field is null, then merge that set into T1.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What you said is right, I did more an assumption than a calculation. My bad, SO looks like I need to thoroughly verify and should get back.

Comment: @ubanerjea I will try what you have suggested. WIll let you know the result. Thank you all

Comment: Use real-time SQL Monitoring to determine exactly what part of the query is slow.  While the query is running, find the SQL_ID from V$SQL and then execute a query like this: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '<sql_id>', type => 'text') from dual;`.  There are *dozens* of reasons why a large query like this could be slow, SQL monitoring removes most of the guesswork.

Comment: Can you trace this with 10046 and upload some results?, Also have you considered bulk_collect / forall ?

Comment: Thanks a lot people, I will try to do as suggested and will update ASAP.